# Background image not starting from top left

Tags: html, css

I have simple html and css as follows:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="top-bar">
            <!-- Hamburger menu-->
            <div class="hamburger-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <!-- Logo-->
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="prod-thumbnail"></div>
    </header>
</body>
```

```
/***** General styles ******/
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 0.7rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/***** Header styles ******/
header {
    display: block;
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

header .top-bar {
    z-index: 2;
}

header .prod-thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #bbb url(../images/some-image.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I intend to give a background image to the `prod-thumbnail` div and create the navigation menu in `top-bar`. I have positioned the `prod-thumbnail` relative to the header. According to the positioning, the `prod-thumbnail` div should start from the top left of the browser, which it does (the background #bbb starts at the top left of the browser), however my background image doesn't start from top left. There is a gap from top as shown in image.

[image: gap from top of browser]

I have tried all possible values for `background-position` property. I have also tried different combinations with `background-size` property with no success. Can anyone tell me what's happening here, as the color background works as expected but the image background doesn't?

Comment: Your line-height in the body may be causing the issue.Try taking it away.

Comment: No, it didn't work by removing line-height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is right. There's nothing wrong with it so... I just can guess your image is like that... with a trasparent top border. Check it out in any image editor

```css
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 0.7rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/***** Header styles ******/
header {
    display: block;
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

header .top-bar {
    z-index: 2;
}

header .prod-thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:  url(https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="top-bar">
            <!-- Hamburger menu-->
            <div class="hamburger-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <!-- Logo-->
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="prod-thumbnail"></div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Np Mate. We all have been there more often than you may think :), that's why I knew it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have ran into this situation many times while coding and I find it much easy and useful when I type

```
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-colour: grey; (you can choose which every colour you want and the * will apply that setting on the whole page)
}
```

This small simple line of code makes sure that there are no problems with where everything starts from. To make sure that this problem does not occur again make sure to type the code above in the starting of your css file